# Вопрос об именах файлов

Tags: android, java, файлы

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот у меня например есть файл с именем `food_meet`, как для сравнения с другим именем использовать только часть имени идущее после символа "_"(`meet`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"food_meet".split("_")[1].equals("другое_имя");
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Comment: Не сработает, если в имени файла больше одного подчёркивания.

Comment: Автор вопроса не просил написать универсальное решение, а лишь для решения конкретной задачи, не так ли?

Comment: Так давайте ещё упростим решение! Давайте напишем `"meet".equals("другое_имя");`! Автор ведь не сказал, что у него будут файлы с другими именами!

Comment: Честно говоря, не совсем понимаю, чего вы хотите. Я дал конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос. А продумать и предусмотреть возможные варианты, не отражённые в вопросе - простите, но я не на работе и мне за это не платят. Если у автора возникнут дополнительные вопросы - отвечу на них. Вполне может быть, что этого частного решения для него окажется достаточно или же подтолкнёт к самостоятельному решению схожей задачи с другими условиями. Предоставьте это решать самому автору вопроса.

Comment: Ну напишите и `"food_meet".lastIndexOf('_');` и перестаньте грызться...

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "food_meet";
String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf('_') + 1);
```